# Left Join and Group

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by

This is my table (table1):

```
id | code | tid | iid |
1  | xx   | 0   | 1   |
2  | xx   | 1   | 0   |
```

Now if I do the SQL

`'SELECT * FROM 'table1' LEFT JOIN 'table_t' ON 'table_t'.'id' = 'table1'.'tid' LEFT JOIN 'table_i' ON 'table_t'.'id' = 'table1'.'iid' GROUP BY 'code'`

Now when I search for the the code 'xxx' and LEFT JOIN the other 2 table's here, the JOIN will JOIN the '0' from the `tid`, but I want to JOIN the '1' (or just the highest number). Does anyone have a good (and fast) SQL for this? Or is it even possible?

I also made a very simple SQLfiddle of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10bc6/1

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * 
from jointable j 
left join tid_table t on t.id = MAX(j.tid) 
left join iid_table i on i.id = MAX(j.iid)
group by code
```

Hope someone can help, I have been searching and trying for hours.

*edit* As you see in the demo, I'm getting "null" for `tid_naam`, this should be `tid-name`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using group by but without any aggregate function so use `MAX()` this will resolve the problem to get the highest value for you field

```
select j.id,j.code,MAX(j.tid)tid,MAX(j.iid) iid ,
t.*,i.*
from jointable j 
left join tid_table t on t.id = j.tid 
left join iid_table i on i.id = j.iid
group by code
```

If you want to search for your code you can do so [*See search demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10bc6/8)

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10bc6/6)

Other way you can use a subselect based on the maxima your columns

```
select j.id,j.code,MAX(j.tid)tid,MAX(j.iid) iid ,
t.*,i.*
from 
(SELECT id,code,MAX(tid)tid,MAX(iid) iid FROM jointable group by code)
 j 
left join tid_table t on t.id = j.tid 
left join iid_table i on i.id = j.iid
group by code
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d10bc6/14)

Comment: No sorry, i explained it wrong i think.. i need something like this (but this doesn't work i know):
`SELECT *
from jointable j 
left join tid_table t on t.id = MAX(j.tid) 
left join iid_table i on i.id = MAX(j.iid)
group by code`

Comment: @MarkvanMarion see my second query in my updated answer